# JDK8 java.time.LocalTime with custom pattern

Tags: java, java-8, java-time

can anyone explain to me why this test is passed:

```
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;

import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.DateTimeParseException;

import static org.hamcrest.core.Is.is;

public class BasicTest extends Assert{

    @Test
    public void testLocalTimeWithPredefinedPattern() throws Exception {
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_TIME;
        LocalTime time = LocalTime.parse("10:11:12", dtf);
        assertThat(time.toString(), is("10:11:12"));
    }

    /**
     * It's a kind of bug from my side of view
     */
    @Test(expected = DateTimeParseException.class)
    public void testLocalTimeWithCustomPattern() throws Exception {
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("hh:mm:ss");
        LocalTime time = LocalTime.parse("10:11:12", dtf);
    }
}
```

Exception caught by second test is looked like this:

```
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '10:11:12' could not be parsed: Unable to obtain LocalTime from TemporalAccessor: {MilliOfSecond=0, MinuteOfHour=11, MicroOfSecond=0, SecondOfMinute=12, NanoOfSecond=0, HourOfAmPm=10},ISO of type java.time.format.Parsed
```

It's a bit illogical, isn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Summary: Use `ISO_LOCAL_TIME`, not `ISO_TIME` and use "H", not "h".

When investigating a parsing problem with `java.time`, make sure to check the error message. In this case, the message was:

```
Text '10:11:12' could not be parsed:
Unable to obtain LocalTime from TemporalAccessor:
{MilliOfSecond=0, MinuteOfHour=11, MicroOfSecond=0,
SecondOfMinute=12, NanoOfSecond=0, HourOfAmPm=10},ISO
of type java.time.format.Parsed
```

(formatted to be easy to read in StackOverflow)

The message tells us that the populated field are:

- HourOfAmPm=10
- MinuteOfHour=11
- SecondOfMinute=12

The fact that it is "HourOfAmPm" rather than "HourOfDay" tells us that the wrong pattern letter has been used, "h" rather than "H". The key is that in `java.time`, the set of populated fields is resolved in a stricter way than the old formatter `DateFormat`. To get a `LocalTime`, either "HourOfDay", or "AmPmOfDay" and "HourOfAmPm", must be specified.

Answer (score 8):

'hh' is for a 1-12 hour and needs an additional am/pm flag. Change it to 'HH' and it should work as expected.

Also note that in your first test you probably want `ISO_LOCAL_TIME`.